# Trouble reading csv file with [] and ''

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to make a simple program that generates a list of URLs that I can then scrape from. I doubt I'm doing this the most efficient way but this what I have.

Is there a way to drop the brackets and single quotation marks in my list?

```
#reads in list of towns that I want to scrape 
f = open('townList.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
towns= []

for row in reader:
    towns.append(row)

#base url. the rest of the url follows the convention 'town-state-abbreviation'
base_url = "https://datausa.io/profile/geo/"

url_list = []

for n in range(len(towns)):
    url = f'{base_url}{towns[n]}{"-pa"}'
    url_list.append(url)

print(url_list)

with open('urls.csv', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in url_list:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

What I get is:

```
https://datausa.io/profile/geo/['Easton']-pa
```

I'd like to get:

```
https://datausa.io/profile/geo/Easton-pa
```

Comment: What is in the file you are reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cvs reader is an iterator of **lists**. A quick fix is probably to do:

```
for row in reader:
    towns.append(row[0])
```

But this is a hint that your file is not a csv file, but a simple sequential one with on value per line. So IMHO, what you want is:

```
#reads in list of towns that I want to scrape 
with open('townList.csv', 'r') as f:
    towns = [line.strip() for line in f]
```